# How to prevent directly accessing assets on a site that requires authentication?

Tags: php, iis-7, security

The company's site is written in PHP, but runs on IIS7.

**Situation:** An unauthenticated user follows a bookmark or manually enters a url of a page.  The user should be redirected to sign in, if they haven't already.

**Current Status** This works, but only for PHP pages.  Each page contains code that checks for an active session and if one is not found, the user is redirected to the sign in page.

**Problem that needs a solution:**
If the user follows a bookmark or manually enters a url of an asset that is not a page (an icon in the page, an excel document, an image, a pdf, etc), we'd like the user to be redirected to sign in.

How do we check for an active session when the user directly accesses non-PHP assets?

In other words, how do we check for an active session for urls like this:

https://www.mysecuresite.com/img/secretpicture.jpg ?

Comment: cheap/dirty/unreliable method: check for the existence of a session cookie.

Comment: @MarcB, yes but how if all they are requesting is /img/pic.jpg?  Is there a way to do this in IIS on each HTTP request and set up a rule to redirect if there is no session?

Comment: @Vidbot: Please contact the vendor of your server software for your support options. They should be able to tell you. If you find out with them, you can post it as an answer here, so the next person who needs to look that up can find an answer (if none yet exists).

Comment: @vidbot: dont' do much with iis, but it should at least be able to do something similar to what mod-rewrite can on apache: check for a cookie and redirect based on its presence/absence.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about IIS, could help with Apache, but uh.. I know some social network that link their static assets via PHP.

So an image link wouldn't be direct, but: /getImage.php?id=secretimage

And there you can check for session first... But yeah, requires some refactoring in your case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is concerned about IIS, not Apache HTTPD.

Comment: Yep, that's why I couldn't help here, but hoping they have an access to sources and even a junior PHP dev who would rewrite the assets request that way.

Comment: This is the approach we've started to take, but there are 13 years worth of links on the site (many of which are hard coded and predate any CMS). The reason this is suddenly a problem is that we plan to open access to the site outside of the internal network (to field sales people).

Comment: How is your users database made? Maybe it is possible to authenticate users automatically if the database is in Windows Domain, so via LDAP or something.